# Query kerberosed database

Tags: jdbc, connection-string, kerberos, impala, apache-kudu

I have an Impala Kudu database secured via Kerberos. Even if I specify the database name in connection string, this will be ignored and I need to use it in my query (which is annoying because I have a lot of queries generated dynamically).

Due of database missing from the query, I get the error *"User X does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT' on default.table"*.

```
connectionString = 'jdbc:impala://domain:port/databaseName;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=NAME;KrbHostFQDN=HOST;...'

query = 'SELECT * FROM tableName;'
```

When time to execute the query is coming, because `connectionString` ignores my database set before, the location will go down one level, and will try to access '`default`' db, where of course, the user don't have privileges.

> User 'username@group' does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT' on:
> default.tableName

So, a solution is to use `dbName.tableName` everywhere in my query. But I hope I can do it from connectionString, because I don't have joins between databases right now, and I don't need to specify it explicitly in my query.

Comment: R u using impala shell? You can use -d 'db_name' option. This will fire qry aginst that particular db.

Comment: Is a Scala Play application, I tought it doesn't matter :d

Comment: see if there is any option to mention the db in the sql.